# need query for this simple pulling data sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am pulling data, but how do I pull from all data listed till an specific range?

Something like

```
select * 
from xxx 
where processdate = '6/30/2013'
```

this gives me all data only for that specific day..

I want data for all the days till 6/30/2013

I am having problems telling the sql to pull data available till 6/30/2013

This will probably be something really simple, but I cant seem to find the function to tell it

Or will I need to look at the data and see the earliest date, and then do a range

Answer (score 3):

It is quite plain, use `<=` or `<` if you want to exclude this day.

```
select * from xxx where processdate <= '6/30/2013'
```